# Drupal 7, user_profile_form form values not passing through drupal_get_form

Tags: forms, drupal

Drupal 7, I want to load the user profile form into a module page. I have a custom field also that the user can configure, let's call this field "blah". It's a implemented as a dropdown field.

When I load the form using the following code everything is fine apart from the blah field which does not populate its user stored data.

```
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
global $user;
$output .= drupal_render((drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user)));
```

Does anyone know how I would get the blah variable/value/user data into this rendered form? It is populated if I go to the standard user profile editing page at http://example.com/user/2/edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! I think the very act of posting on Stack Overflow sometimes brings you around to working it out. It was just as simple as `$user->field_blah['und'][0]['value'] = 12345;`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this using [user_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7) api.

```
global $user;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
print_r($user_fields);
```

Comment: Thank you Sumoanand. I had managed to get the user variables from user_load, I just can't seem to load them into the form itself.

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solutions:-
1)If its a custom field make it belong to user entity bundle and true for user register form while attaching it to user bunble.
2)U can use field_attach_form,
3)form alter